# How to make sure I've closed the connection in one connection pool before I get another connection in other connection pool?

Tags: java, connection

How to make sure I've closed the connection in one connection pool before I get another connection in other connection pool?

Comment: Just invoke its `close()` method? What's your concrete problem? Why don't you just ask a question about the concrete problem instead of about a "possible solution" which you thought (which after all isn't the right solution to your concrete problem).

Answer (score 0):

A call to close() method will make sure your connection is release. You can also add a call to close() method in the finalize() method of the object where you are using the connection so that the connection is definitely released at some point of time although it is advised not to depend on finalize() method..

Comment: I had a call to close() method,but it didn't work,thanks as well……